# Is there a strong correlation between speech rate and beat rate in English

Tags: pronunciation, speech, syllables

Can speech rate in English be reliably measured through the beat rate?

Beat rate analysis is now pretty standard, and a plethora of algorithms can reliably measure beat rate — typically in beats per minute (bpm) — of all sorts of formats (e.g. mp3, wav, ogg, etc). Speech rate analysis is typically done by transcribing recorded speech, and measuring it — usually in words per minute, and more robustly in syllables per minute (or per second, no difference) — but could perhaps be well approximated via the bpm measure.

Can it? Does each word in English correlate to a beat via a single tonic syllable?

Comment: I think you want to look at *morae*. I don't think there will be a reliable (R^2 > 0.7) correlation between tonic syllables and the average BPM. Only one way to find out, right?

Comment: Could you clarify what you are thinking of when you say "beat rate analysis is now pretty standard"? I'm wondering in what context people have used this sort of analysis effectively

Comment: @sumelic: [How to detect the BPM of a song](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657073/how-to-detect-the-bpm-of-a-song-in-php)